# javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <iam.jp-tok.bluemix.net> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names

Tags: websphere, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

i am using the IBM Cloud Bluemix Push-notification services and the IBM Push java SDK Client integrated with spring boot application.

When i trigger the push notification to Tokyo region bluemix instance getting the below exception .

This one is happening with only ***Tokyo (japan region instance)*** for other regions no issues.

Does any one faced this issue earlier and any solution handy ?

```
2020-05-07 02:40:57.644 ERROR 12377 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.i.m.s.java.push.PushNotifications      : javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <iam.jp-tok.bluemix.net> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.bluemix.net, bluemix.net]

javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <iam.jp-tok.bluemix.net> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.bluemix.net, bluemix.net]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:507) ~[httpclient-4.5.10.jar:4.5.10]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:437) ~[httpclient-4.5.10.jar:4.5.10]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384) ~[httpclient-4.5.10.jar:4.5.10]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) ~[httpclient-4.5.10.jar:4.5.10]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374) ~[httpclient-4.5.10.jar:4.5.10]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393) ~[httpclient-4.5.10.jar:4.5.10]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236) ~[httpclient-4.5.10.jar:4.5.10]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186) ~[httpclient-4.5.10.jar:4.5.10]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.10.jar:4.5.10]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient-4.5.10.jar:4.5.10]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.10.jar:4.5.10]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.10.jar:4.5.10]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108) ~[httpclient-4.5.10.jar:4.5.10]
```